# HTML: Loading JSON in <pre> and <code> element; adding line breaks

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to display the content of a json file on a web page nicely.
That's how I do it:

```
{
  "name": "Hans",
  "age": 12,
  "favorite food": "Spätzlepfanne",
  "siblings": false
}
```

(silly example ... I know :D)

```
function loadJSON(url, callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType('application/json');
    xobj.open('GET', url, true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == '200') {
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    };
    xobj.send(null);
}
```

and the HTML-Stuff:

```
<pre><code id="code1"></code></pre>
<script>
    loadJSON("../v0.1/json/hans.json", function(resText){
        data_parsed = JSON.parse(resText);
        //data.age = 33;
        data_stringified = JSON.stringify(data_parsed);
        document.getElementById("code1").innerHTML = resText;
    })
</script>
```

You probably recognized another issue: I am displaying the `resText`, which I am not able to change once it's loaded. I would like to display either the JavaScript object (`data_parsed`) to let Hans age a bit, like in the comment, or the stringified object.

The main problem is, that the output on my web page is:

> [object Object] for ...innerHTML = data_parsed

or

> {"name":"Hans","age":12,"favorite food":"Spätzlepfanne","sibli
>   (a long one liner) for ...innerHTML = data_stringified

I really want to be the information about Hans displayed like in that example:
https://jsoneditoronline.org/#/

A nicely and cool looking field for code, where the JSON is being displayed and with the opportunity to change something.

My idea:
something like "add line break after every ','" ... I don't know

I am open for better approaches. :)  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you are stringifying the data, you should use `data_parsed` rather than `data`. Also, `JSON.stringify` takes the third argument as the number of spaces you want while beautifying JSON and making a string that you can set to `innerHTML`.

You can check the below snippet.

```
data_parsed = JSON.parse(resText);
//data.age = 33;
data_stringified = JSON.stringify(data_parsed, null, 4);
document.getElementById("code1").innerHTML = data_stringified;
```

That should work.

Comment: Could you explain what you've changed from OP's code ? SO is more about explaining issue rather than feeding code to those you demand it.

Comment: I thought because of the few line changes, it is self-explanatory. But anyhow, I have added the description above. Thanks for notifying me. :-)

Comment: But does it also look like the example he provided?

Comment: That work's perfectly! :D Thank you very much! What does that do?

Comment: It does look like my example. I really like that! :) Thanks!

Comment: @Soxxes, there are some changes which I have mentioned above the code snippet.

Comment: @NikhilGoyal, I love it! :) Thanks ... again.